# How to play DRM content in chromecast from flutter

Tags: flutter, casting, flutter-dependencies, chromecast, drm

Is it possible to play DRM content in Chromecast from **flutter** application. If possible let us know the code clues.

Here is the sample code for playing DRM content with shaka player in web version. Adding this link just to refer the license passing for DRM content.
https://shaka-player-demo.appspot.com/docs/api/tutorial-license-server-auth.html

Comment: Can you cast normal content? I wasn't able to. I'd be glad if you share which package you use or how did you implement it.

Comment: You can use the following package for this. It will play the videos which can be played directly in browsers.  https://pub.dev/packages/dart_chromecast

Comment: Thanks alot. I'm trying to use this package https://pub.dev/packages/cast
It looks more up-to-date than the others since it supports null safety.